# Software that simulates a cookie marker

Tags: template-design

I have observed several work with cookie cutters and markers on the internet and I believe that not all of them are real.
I've been doing some Photoshop and InkScape tests to get similar results, but I haven't found any satisfactory patterns to get this result.
Does anyone know which technique I should look for for best results?

The image below illustrates what I want:

[image]

Comment: Any 3D aplication that has a sub surface shader does this. But might be better for you to just use PS as it can easily do this.

Answer (score 4):

It can be done with ordinary 2D tools Photoshop and Illustrator. Their 3D effects are flexible enough in simple cases. A couple of guesses:

1. You are not interested in the punching tool, you want to make a plausible hole to a piece of uncooked food material.
2. Straight on the face view (=directly downwards) is not the interesting one - that could be done easily with Photoshop effects, but it cannot be inserted to a photo which has tilted view. You expect something like this:

[image]

Start the job in Illustrator. Prepare an outlined black version of the wanted hole. It must have no strokes, it must be a strokeless filled area, so expand strokes and make an union.

Subtract a copy of the hole image from a grey rectangle with Pathfinder > Minus Front.

[image]

Paste to illustrator a copy of your food material photo, Place the black shape on it and search for it a good orientation and perspective angles with 3D effect Rotate. Do not use the grey version for this, because the rectangle can disturb the appearance remarkably.

[image]

Move the black shape away. Insert the grey version and apply effect 3D > Bevel&Extrude to it. Use the same viewing and perspective angles which you found with 3D Rotate.

[image]

Adjust the light so that there's good contrast, but avoid full black and white. They are difficult to adjust later.

The rectangle looks wrong due the curved surface, but you remove it later.

Copy and paste the extruded version in Photoshop as a new pixel layer to your food material photo. Before you nail the pasting adjust the size and placement to approximately the same as it was in Illustrator:

[image]

Insert below the pasted image a new layer (=Fill). Paint to it grey color which fills the transparent holes. The grey must be darker than the flat top surface and lighter than the vertical surfaces:

[image]

I painted the same nearly 50% grey that covers the top flat area and adjusted with curves the Fill layer to good contrast.

Merge the grey layers, make a lasso selection and remove the extruded outer edges:

[image]

Make a low tolerance (=2) Magic Wand selection and delete all grey except the holes. Have Anti-alias ON for smooth edges:

[image]

Change the blending mode of the grey layer to Hard Light. Adjust the color of the grey layer with Image > Adjustments > Hue/Saturation > Colorize:

[image]

It was simple, but you get better control with adjustment layers. They must have "the next image layer only" -switch ON to prevent coloring the food material:

[image]

Finally the shape must be distorted to follow the surface curvature. In this case it's easy, because the shape has no strict rectagular forms and the food material surface is simple. The eye accepts easily quite coarse warp.

Select the shape by applying Ctrl+Click to its layer icon in the Layers panel. Apply Edit > Transform > Warp and drag lines and handles:

[image]

You may want some of the holes to be shallower than the others. To get it you must extrude them separately in Illustrator.

If you zoom in you may see that the food material photo isn't especially sharp. The stamp looks sharper. The photo was originally a low resolution screenshot from a meat webshop and it's only resized to high enough pixel dimensions (=1750 x 1050) to present the stamp properly in Photoshop. That's a contradiction. For more plausible results the photo should have originally the needed resolution for the stamp insertion.

Answer (score 1):

I use very often 3D software. I know how difficult is to add errors so a render looks realistic. It is funny how on a real photo you clean the subject to be perfect, and on a 3D render you add imperfections to make it real.

---

I am pretty sure that is a real photo. The mold itself looks like it is a 3D print made of plastic. You can see how the sugar glass is pushed between the lines of text.

The mold itself has some particular reflections consistent with a rough plastic 3D print.

If it were a 3D image, it would mean a lot of work... and you do not waste all that work in that simplistic lighting and framing as the sample image. So that is just a photo.

---

But answering your question, a quick approach I would use is using a 3D program, specifically Blender, https://www.blender.org/ and use a tool called Boolean operations, this is you extrude a 3D text, use it as the mold and make the boolean operation to make a hole on a surface.

Then add a bevel to smooth the edges.

This is not an easy task if you are new to a 3D program. But that is the road if you want to follow it.